# How to update my View in Drupal 8 without scrolling back to the top?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I'm trying to refresh my View in Drupal 8 without reloading the page with this code :

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  setInterval(function() {
    $('.view-message-activity-stream-timeline-public').trigger('RefreshView');
  }, 10000);

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

It works.

**My problem :**

Each time the view is refreshed, that page scolls back to the top of the view.

There is another problem with the refresh of the page. When I click the "Afficher plus" link at the bottom of the home page, page 2 appears below page 1, but it automatically closes when the page is refreshed.

https://www.s1biose.com/

Comment: "*it goes back up*", can you develop a bit ?

Comment: @EricLavault You can test on the next page. Scroll down the page and wait 10 seconds. The page goes back automatically to each update https://www.s1biose.com/fr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the `ViewAjaxController` adding up the `ScrollTopCommand` to the ajax response every time it loads/reloads a view. You can find the involved lines in the method `ajaxView`:

```
if (isset($pager_element)) {
  $response->addCommand(new ScrollTopCommand(".js-view-dom-id-$dom_id"));
  $view->displayHandlers->get($display_id)->setOption('pager_element', $pager_element);
}
```

Fortunately, it is possible to alter the command data that is sent to the client by implementing the [`hook_ajax_render_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/8.2.x), just remove the `viewsScrollTop` command so that it is no longer triggered:

```
function <MODULE>_ajax_render_alter(array &$data) {
  $view_name = '<view_name>';
  $view_dom_id = '<view_dom_id>';
  $selector = '.js-view-dom-id-' . $view_dom_id;

  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['command'] === 'viewsScrollTop' && $value['selector'] === $selector) {
      unset ($data[$key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to match the `view_dom_id` with the `view_name`, you can search for the `settings` command in the $data array, eg. `$cmd['settings']['views']['ajaxViews']` has a structure that looks like the following, note the array key precisely being built up from the views_dom_id :

```
[ajaxViews] => Array
    (
        [views_dom_id:<views_dom_id>] => Array
            (
                [view_name] => <view_name>
                [view_display_id] => <view_display_id>
                [view_dom_id] => <views_dom_id>
            )

    )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your solution works. I updated my question. I do not know if I have to open a new question because the problem is related.

Comment: I see, yes it is related but I think it deserves its own post. Create/search for a question that mentions something like "ajax refresh a view with infinite scroll while preserving its pager element, loaded items and scroll position". I'll check back later.

Comment: I opened a new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956275/how-to-update-my-view-in-drupal-8-without-going-back-to-the-first-page