# How to update my view in Drupal 8 without going back to the first page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal-8, drupal-views

I'm trying to refresh my View in Drupal 8 without reloading the page with this code :

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  setInterval(function() {
    $('.view-message-activity-stream-timeline-public').trigger('RefreshView');
  }, 10000);

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

My module :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Holds hook implementation for the Message Activity Stream module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\message\Entity\Message;

/**
 * Implements hook_ajax_render_alter().
 */
function message_activity_stream_ajax_render_alter(array &$data) {
  foreach ($data as $key => $command) {
    if ($command['command'] === 'viewsScrollTop') {
      unset($data[$key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_user_insert(User $account) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_user_register', 'uid' => $account->id()]);
  $message->set('field_user_reference', $account);
  $message->save();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_store_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_commerce_store_insert(Store $commerce_store) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_store', 'uid' => $commerce_store->get('uid')]);
  $message->set('field_store_reference', $commerce_store);
  $message->save();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_product_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_commerce_product_insert(Product $commerce_product) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_product', 'uid' => $commerce_product->get('uid')]);
  $message->set('field_product_reference', $commerce_product);
  $message->save();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_group_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_group_insert(Group $group) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_group', 'uid' => $group->get('uid')]);
  $message->set('field_group_reference', $group);
  $message->save();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_node_insert(Node $node) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_node', 'uid' => $node->get('uid')]);
  $message->set('field_node_reference', $node);
  $message->save();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_comment_insert(Comment $comment) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_comment', 'uid' => $comment->getOwnerId()]);
  $message->set('field_comment_reference', $comment);
  $message->save();
}
```

It works.

**My problem :**

At the bottom of my page I have a pagination button "Afficher plus" (the button that is the full width of the page). When the page refreshes automatically (every 10 seconds), it returns to the first page.

https://www.s1biose.com/fr