# How to update a DIV automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval, drupal-8

I have a site with a DIV that I want to refresh automatically every 2 seconds.

Here is the HTML structure :

block--system-branding-block.html.twig

```
{% extends "block--bare.html.twig" %}
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a branding block.
 *
 * Each branding element variable (logo, name, slogan) is only available if
 * enabled in the block configuration.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - site_logo: Logo for site as defined in Appearance or theme settings.
 * - site_name: Name for site as defined in Site information settings.
 * - site_slogan: Slogan for site as defined in Site information settings.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 */
#}
{% block content %}

{{ attach_library('message_activity_stream/message_activity_stream.logo_notify') }}
<div id="site-branding-logo">

  {% if site_logo %}
    {% if logged_in %}
      {{ drupal_view('message_activity_stream_timeline_private', 'block_3') }}
    {% else %}
      <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
        <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_name %}
    <a class="name navbar-brand" href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_slogan %}
    <p class="navbar-text">{{ site_slogan }}</p>
  {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

message_activity_stream.libraries.yml

```
message_activity_stream.unread_message_counter:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/unread_messages_counter.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal

message_activity_stream.logo_notify:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/logo_notify.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.ajax

message_activity_stream.switch_tabs:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/switch_tabs.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

logo_notify.js

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $("#site-branding-logo")
    }, 2000);
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

My code does not work. The logo is not updated automatically.

How to update a DIV automatically ?

I want to update the DIV with the class `region-navigation-logo`

Comment: What should trigger the automatic update?

Comment: Your question is unclear and it doesn't show any effort on your part to solve your issue. What do you mean by "I want to update the DIV with the class region-navigation-logo"? Update it how? With what? What did you try?

Comment: I just want to update the div periodically

Comment: I'm not familiar with that templating framework so I don't know about that part, but how are you expecting that `setInterval` to update anything? There is nothing in it that would even start to update the content -- `$("#site-branding-logo")` literally does nothing.

Comment: There is nothing to update with this code `$("#site-branding-logo")` it just grabs the corresponding DOM element as a jQuery object. So what do you mean by refresh ? Where is the new information/content ? I remember you struggling with a view 'message_activity_stream' to refresh or something like that, you want to refresh the div's content that is the view right ?

Comment: If it's related you should stick with views api using `$(some-view).trigger('RefreshView');` that actually makes an ajax request and update the content accordingly. So I suggest to close this post and edit the one that really describes the problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/56956275/2529954 so it will pop on top of active questions, I just upvoted it so you can get more attention (I may be totally wrong but anyway your issue is not well described here in this post).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the traditional innerHTML setting? If you can use javascript (I didn't see you say either way) then you can set up script like this:

```
function update_logo ( new_logo_html ) {
    // get handle for the logo div
    var logo_div = document.getElementsByClassName("region-navigation-logo");
    // Replace the <div> html with the html passed
    logo_div.innerHTML = new_logo_html;
}
```

... and call this from a timer.

More info about your environment would help us give a more specific answer.

Comment: The update should help - that's a lot more info for us Stack Overflow Elves to work with. Unfortunately I don't recognize that {% else %} notation, so I'm not going to be much help; but I"m sure someone else will. I did up-vote your question due to the added info. Good luck.